# Learning how to read schematics, questions about fractional voltage in schematic

Tags: ground, schematics

In a schematic I've been reviewing I see in only one spot that there is a 1/2v going somewhere? What does that mean?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fmMaOM.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

[image]

Comment: The schematic you've laid out here doesn't make sense, because a ground symbol is _what we consider to be 0 V_ so marking it with a voltage is contradictory. Could you provide a photo/screenshot of the original schematic rather than your redrawing? There might be some subtlety missing. Other context such as what the schematic is supposed to be a part of, or demonstrate, might also be useful. (But thanks for taking the time to do the embedded schematic — it's _usually_ better than alternatives!)

Comment: @KevinReid I've added the full schematic and highlighted the spots that the 1/2v shows up (it in two places actually)

Comment: @greyBow It just means, in this case, \$4.5\:\text{V}\$.

Comment: @KevinReid Oh okay, I see, so the 1M resistor brings it down to 4.5v? But then where would it go?

Comment: @greyBow NO NO NO! Look at the two \$10\:\text{k}\Omega\$ resistors, \$R_{20}\$ and \$R_{21}\$!!!

Comment: :( that symbol choice was pretty bad (especially in addition with this ground symbol instead of 3 lines)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Look at the top of `R20` - that is labeled `V` and is the supply rail. (`V` is also connected to `9VDC` which is the power input - see the DC connector and battery, towards the top left of the schematic.)

Therefore, as commented by *jonk*, the node at the junction of equal resistors `R20` and `R21` must be half of `V` hence `1/2V` means exactly that.

Also, looking carefully, the arrow symbols labeled `1/2V` are slightly smaller than the arrows which are the ground symbol. On the full schematic you can compare their size and see the difference - but otherwise, that choice of arrow by the designer could easily be confusing! As kindly pointed out by *Kevin* in the comments, that smaller arrow is being used here as the symbol for a named node.

Comment: Might be worth pointing out that the same arrow symbol is used to connect "9VDC". So it's a general named node symbol.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, so then does that mean that 1/2v coming off the junction between r20 and r21 would then connect to the 1/2v coming off of R2?

Comment: @greyBow Yes. Those nets are tied together.

Comment: @greyBow - Yes, exactly that. That "half the supply voltage" is being used to bias the gate of `Q1` via `R2`.

Comment: I see. Thank you SO much for the help, this has been extremely helpful. Many, many thanks!

Comment: That wording is confusing as well. I would label it V/2 or something; "1/2V" makes me think it means 0.5V.

Answer (score 6):

The down arrow below R2 in the original schematic is not a Ground symbol - it indicates "this point is connected to something that-a-way" - it connects to an upward-pointing arrow in the power supply section below.  That point will be at half the 9 V power supply voltage due to R20 and R21.  It provides an appropriate bias voltage for Q1.

Drawing a line to show the connection would make much more sense.

Edit: as @kevin pointed out, that narrow arrow symbol is used as a general named signal marker - all such arrows with the same name will be connected together.